# Entity Framework Paged Join and Unions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm developing a new web interface for a database with the following structure:

```
Categories Table (ID, Name, Active, ...)
Products Table (ID, Name, ItemNo, Price, Active, ...)
WebPages Table (ID, Name, Active, ...)
Links Table (ID, Name, Href, Target, Active, ...)
Relations Table (ID, ParentCategoryID, CmsForeignKeyID, CmsItemType, SortOrder, Visible)
```

The Relations table is used to establish relations between a parent category and its children, which can be categories, products, webpages, or links.

I need to be able to get back a paged list of the child nodes for a given parent category. The nodes have to be Active, Visible, and Sorted (default SortOrder then by Name).

I tried doing some things with EF/LINQ and had issues JOINing Relations because of needing multiple criteria (example: R.CmsForeignKeyID = N.ID, R.CmsItemType = 1) so I didn't even get to the unions and paging.

Would it be best to forego EF as a tool in this scenario and do it with traditional SQL, something like:

```
SELECT C.CategoryID As ID, R.CmsItemTypeID, C.Name, R.SortOrder, '' AS Href, '' As LinkTarget, null As MSRP, null As ListPrice, null As Price
FROM kc_Relations R
JOIN kc_Categories C ON R.CmsItemID = C.CategoryID AND R.CmsItemTypeID = 1
WHERE C.IsActive = 1 AND R.IsVisible = 1
UNION
SELECT W.WebPageID As ID, R.CmsItemTypeID, W.Name, R.SortOrder, '' AS Href, '' As LinkTarget, null AS MSRP, null As ListPrice, null As Price
FROM kc_Relations R
JOIN kc_WebPages W ON R.CmsItemID = W.WebPageID AND R.CmsItemTypeID = 0
WHERE W.IsActive = 1 AND R.IsVisible = 1
UNION
SELECT P.ProductID As ID, R.CmsItemTypeID, P.Name, R.SortOrder, '' AS Href, '' As LinkTarget, P.MSRP, P.ListPrice, P.Price
FROM kc_Relations R
JOIN kc_Products P ON R.CmsItemID = P.ProductID AND R.CmsItemTypeID = 2
WHERE P.IsActive = 1 AND R.IsVisible = 1
UNION
SELECT L.LinkID As ID, R.CmsItemTypeID, L.Name, R.SortOrder, L.Href, L.Target As LinkTarget, null As MSRP, null AS ListPrice, null AS Price
FROM kc_Relations R
JOIN kc_Links L ON R.CmsItemID = L.LinkID AND R.CmsItemTypeID = 3
WHERE L.IsActive = 1 AND R.IsVisible = 1
```

And then do the paging logic on the resultset? Or is there a better way to structure the DB that will make this easier?

Comment: After reading through my problem statement again, I just realized that I don't need two conditions on each of the JOINs; I can specify the CmsItemTypeID in a WHERE clause for each query. Will try that tonight and see if it eliminates the error I was getting. If not, I was thinking another way to go about this might be to create a view for this query. Entity Framework can do paged queries on views, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought on views kind of pointed me in the right direction. After some additional testing, I was able to get this to work. You have to set the same properties in the SELECT portion of the LINQ query for each part of the UNION in order for it to work. If you don't have a value, you still have to manually set it to a default (null). Example:

```
(from c in Categories select new { ID = c.CategoryId, Name = c.Name, Price = null })
.UNION
(from p in Products select new { ID = p.ProductId, Name = p.Name, Price = p.Price })
```

Comment: The LINQ `IEnumerable<T>.Union` operator only has the first letter in its name capitalized. As I recall, VB.NET is case-insensitive; but this wouldn't compile in C#.

Comment: You are correct Justin. I was typing in by hand and capitalized it out of habit because I always capitalize keywords when writing SQL. The C# code I ended up with uses .Union